# Get Firestore Server Timestamp from the client side

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

I'm building an app that tracks time. It calculates the time by differentiating the seconds like so:

```
serverTimestamp: FieldValue // {seconds: number, milliseconds: number}.

getSeconds() {
  const createdTime = new Date(this.serverTimestamp * 1000).getTime()
  const currentTime = new Date().getTime();

  return Math.abs((currentTime - createdTime) / 1000);
}
```

The problem is that `Date`'s values equal to the current client's device clock, while firestore's timestamp equal to the firestore server, which may cause inequivalence between these two dates.

The leads me with two alternatives:

#### 1. Save `Date` instead of `serverTimestamp()`.

This way, the difference between these two dates will be accurate. Although, they won't represent the real date. Plus, if the user will change his clock on his machine, then the seconds would be changed too.

#### 2. Create an HTTPS function that retrieves the current server timestamp.

This way, the difference between these two dates will be accurate either. Although, it feels like I'm going too far only to get the current timestamp of the server.

I am probably going to stick with alternative number two. But I was hoping if there's a better solution to achieve my goal.

*PS - I'm using @angular/fire. So, solutions from this package would be welcomed.*

Answer (score 0):

You can also write the current timestamp with a serverTimestamp, then read the time back out of the location it was just written.  Then you can make changes or calculations with that value.

Comment: Assuming I understood your solution, It could work until I refresh the page or open the page from another device because I'm not writing to my database every time the app is initializing. Therefore, I can't read the time back.